# How to access android app data from windows using usb

Tags: android, filesystems

The app is called notpad by anton lashkov. I tried the in app way but it export notes individually.

I have tried accessing the app files through android filesysyem and windows but the app file shows empty on both.

how can i access all my notes so i can copy them all?.

thanks!!

Comment: Hi @androidapps, welcome on stack overflow! Please, can you edit your question in order to make it more clear to other users? 

At first glance it was not very clear to me if the problem happens on an application made by you or if it's downloaded, and what you're trying to accomplish.

Titles should be more a description than a question (e.g. "Read data stored by an Android App on Windows"). Then you are free to give more details in the description, with code or screenshots if needed. Tags are also a good way to address the question to the right public!

Comment: To give you an answer instead, I think that it all depends on how this particular app is saving the data: it may save the notes as txt files or another format. Many applications use an internal database (like SQLite), which you may or may not read, depending on the security level: if the data is encrypted, then there's not much you can do. Further information in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data). Good luck!

It's not completely true that wha

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
Can you imagine the danger that would it would be if everyone could access the internal app files? Imagine knowing some sensible data of per example, Whatsapp or facebook...